# Delphi 11.2 - Phone Dialer does not works

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am using Delphi 11.2 and the call phone function on android does not works anymore. When I start the app it's stop to working. Using the Delphi samples PhoneDialer project the same error.

Any idea ?

Regards.

Comment: Revoked permission?

Comment: I think no because the app lock when starts. I am deploying on a Samsung A23 and when I remove the unit FMX.PhoneDialer from uses the app open. Off course without phone dialer function.

Comment: The obvious first candidate is - has it got permissions to the phone

Comment: yes has. The app simply does not works. On a Motorola Android One (Android 12) works.

Comment: @RohitGupta analyzing the unit FMX.PhoneDialer has the code: **initialization
{$IF Defined(IOS) OR Defined(ANDROID)}
  RegisterPhoneDialerService;
{$ENDIF}** And something about Dialer changes but what?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @RohitGupta Steps to reproduce: </br> 1) Open the Embarcadero examples:  
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Mobile Snippets\PhoneDialer </br> 2) On a Samsung device Serie A?? try to execute the app </br>

Comment: I have S9, I could try it on that tomorrow.

Comment: Fantastic! My workaround was remove the unit FMX.PhoneDialer from the uses clause and stop this function temporally. Doing this all app works fine.

Comment: @rohitgupta I take a look at app permissions in Applications, select the app and in permissions setting up manually Phone grant and the app works. However, how to do it via code ? I am using the Embarcadero example and the phone call grant is called after press the "Call" button but the app lock when starts. So I cannot press the but.

Comment: You can't do it via code.  That is the **purpose** of permissions so viruses and bad programs can't allocate it to themselves.  Do you mind upvoting my comment to indicate that it had a positive effect.

Comment: sure! How to do it?

Comment: It's because of this issue: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-39445
Workaround with steps is in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Although it's trivial, I think it may be best to document it as an answer.

Many of the resources on the phone require that the **user grants permission** for using them.  The purpose of this mechanism is to stop viruses and badly behaved applications from running without the user's knowledge.

**Phone** is such a resource.  You will need to grant your app permission to use it.  It is not enough that your app checks if it has been granted or if you have registered the **PhoneDialerService**.